# setting a font seperatly for ios5 and lower

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts, uibutton, storyboard

I have recently started using avenir as the font for my button text in my storyboard. It looks normal when I run it on ios6 [image], however in ios5 and lower as it doesn't support avenir it just uses the system default which looks awful aswell as the text not all fiting in the button, like so [image]

Can anyone tell me how I would select a different font and text size for ios5, or a different font and text size when it returns nil to avenir?

Comment: are you setting the font programmatically? If so then create and assign a new font using [UIFont fontWithName:size:] if the the avenir font is nil.

Comment: @SpencerHall nope, i just use storyboards, i never programme it.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"iOS 6 font" size:SIZE];
if (!font) {
    font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Legacy font" size:SIZE];
}
```

Comment: where do i put this code? i have never programmed the design i just do it in the storyboard

Comment: do i need to put something in .h aswell?